# emacs paredit - how to delete quotes

Tags: javascript, emacs, paredit

I'm using the emacs starter kit, https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit, which comes with paredit mode.
I'm writing some javascript, and would like to remove something from quotes.
Eg. `"somestring"` should become `somestring`

What the best way to do that?
Going in the other direction is easy, I just select `somestring` and type a quote.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use M-s to splice the current form into the outer form. This works with quotes, parentheses, and similar stuff, depending on the exact mode you're in:

```
(bla (|foo))  -> (bla |foo)
(bla "|foo")  -> (bla |foo)
```

Where | is the position of the cursor when you press M-s.

Comment: adding the ParEdit reference table link: [Paredit reference table](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.html)

Answer (score 15):

If you're on the first quote, you can <kbd>M-x delete-pair</kbd>.  If you do it all the time, bind that to some convenient key.

Answer (score 6):

Put point anywhere on the string and type <kbd>M-s</kbd> or <kbd>M-x paredit-splice-sexp</kbd>.